# Laravel 9 [webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, laravel-9

I downloaded a laravel 9 template and I am trying to run and use it but every time I try `npm run dev` I get the error `[webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function`.

Comment: How did you download this Laravel template? did you change anything before running `npm run dev`? Also did you run `npm install` and did it work without any issues?

Comment: I downloaded it from envato elements. And yes I did `npm install`

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. Check if there are integration instructions with a Laravel app (which I am assuming you need to have prior to installing a template for it)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by reinstalling `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` which, according to the error, is the plugin that causes the error. Here are the following commands that solved my problem:

```
npm uninstall browser-sync-webpack-plugin

npm install browser-sync-webpack-plugin
```

It upgraded this plugin's package.JSON's line from `"^2.0.1" to "^2.3.0".`

I think I should update all my NPM plugins (see NPm commands npm outdated and npm update).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had tried this severally from one of the answers to a similar issue. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it means that one of the plugins needs to be updated